# unexpected non-greedy JS regular expression result

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does

```
/<.+?> e/.exec("a <b> c <d> e")
```

(unexpectedly) return

```
["<b> c <d> e"]
```

instead of

```
["<d> e"]
```

The non-greedy operator seems to be doing nothing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can make you understand the role of the lazy operator:

```js
/<.+?> e/.exec("a <b> c <d> e <f> e")` // -> ["<b> c <d> e", "<f> e"]
/<.+> e/.exec("a <b> c <d> e <f> e")`  // -> ["<b> c <d> e <f> e"]
```

`<.+?> e` means: *once a `<` is found, find the **first** `> e`*

`<.+> e` means: *once a `<` is found, find the **last** `> e`*

In your specific case, you could simply use `<[^>]+> e` (which is even better since quicklier - when its possible, always prefer the `X[^X]X` notation rather than the `X.*?X` one).

Answer (score 3):

`"<b> c <d> e"` is a totally valid result. Your regexp says "match `<` then something, then `> e`" - this is exactly what you're getting. "Intuitively" `"<d> e"` might look like a better match, however, a regex engine has no intuition, it just finds the first substring that matches and stops there.

Greediness comes into play when you have a choice between two or more matches - this is not the case here, because there's only one match. If your string had two `> e`, there would be a difference:

```
/<.+> e/.exec("a <b> c <d> e more > e")
> ["<b> c <d> e more > e"]
/<.+?> e/.exec("a <b> c <d> e more > e")
> ["<b> c <d> e"]
```

Comment: `non-greedy operator seems to be doing nothing`

Comment: @shiplu: Please explain ".. seems to be doing nothing". The string found by the greedy expression (top) is 9 characters longer than the string found by the non-greedy expression -- and the non-greedy `?` is the only difference. Hence, by observation the operator *does* 'something'.

Answer (score 3):

The `?` is making it non-greedy, the behaviour you're experiencing is happening because you're not telling it to end attempting to match at a `>` which is not part of `> e`. Currently;

```
/<.+?> e/
```

1. Go through text until `<`
2. match until `>` or end of line

   1. If it was end of line, return `null`
   2. If it was `>`

      1. If it is `> e`, complete match
      2. Otherwise, include and resume `2`

Remember, `.+` will happily match `>`, spaces and letters, so these get included. Looks like you wanted

```
/<[^>]+?> e/
```

1. Go through text until `<`
2. match all non `>`
3. `>` or end of line found

   1. If it was end of line, return `null`
   2. If it was `>`

      1. If it is `> e`, complete match
      2. Otherwise, go back to step `1`

Resulting in

```
/<[^>]+?> e/.exec("a <b> c <d> e")
// ["<d> e"]
```

This happens because when it encounters a `>` which is not part of `> e`, it knows it's starting position must have been wrong, so continues along the text again until the next `<`.

Comment: Thats not the answer. greedy operation is not working here `?` thats the problem

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: non-greedy works fine but you have a wrong conception of what non-greedy means - it just says that the shortest possible match among all those starting at the same test string position will be chosen whereas you erroneously believe that the shortest of right-aligned matches will be selected, ie. that a match decision will be revised down the line (no offence intended as i haven't been aware of it either).

Comment: Please add this comment in your main answer.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im does my last edit now explain more clearly?

Comment: "you erroneously believe that the shortest of right-aligned matches will be selected, ie. that a match decision will be revised down the line" ... that was the critical piece I was missing, thanks @collapsar!

Answer (score 2):

From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html):

> This is a very important point to understand: a regex-directed engine
>   will always return the leftmost match, even if a "better" match could
>   be found later.

The regex engine walks its way through the string from the left, and for each character, says "can I find a match starting here?" The non-greedy operator will never prevent a match from being found when one would be found without it, so the engine will keep trying, meaning when it checks starting from the first `<`, it'll find a match and return it right away (without ever checking for a match starting from the second `<`, because it doesn't make it that far).

In order to match what it seems like you want, a single set of angle brackets followed by an "e", you just make sure there's no `>` in the middle"

```
<[^>]+>[ ]e
```

(Note the space is in a character class for clarity, not because it needs to be.)

Answer (score 2):

By making `.+` lazy, the pattern has to find a matching `> e` right after the *first* occurance of `<.+?`. Since that, in your case is the substring `<b> c`, the rest of the pattern `> e`, doesn't match yet, so the `.+` part of your expression keeps on going, until, finally  the `> e` part is matched in the end...

```
'a <b> c <d> e'
 xx//<-- no matches
   <//<-- opening < matches, switch to .+?
    b//<-- matched by .+
     > c//<-- does not match > e, but does match .+
         <d// matched by .+
           > e// matches rest of expression (> e), the resulting match is:

   <b> c <d> e
```

Instead of using a lazy operator, in your case, I'd simply go for:

```
/(?:<)[^>]+> e/
//or even
/<[^>]+>\s+e/
```